# Find all continuous functions $f:R \rightarrow R$ which take irrational values only at rational points and not at irrational points.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, connectedness

Find all continuous functions $f:R \rightarrow  R$ which take irrational values only at rational points and not at irrational points.

My approach: We know that image of a continuous map from $R \rightarrow  R$ (connected set) to an  interval or singleton. In case of non-constant and continuous map, it cant map to singleton thus it maps to interval which is uncountable where as    $f(R)=f(Q) \cup f(Q^c)\subseteq f(Q) \cup Q$  is countable, hence a contradiction.

My question is: Does there exist a constant continuous map satisfying above condition? If not then how to reject it.

Comment: Well, a constant function takes only one value, so it shouldn't be difficult to verify whether it satisfies the condition...have you tried to do so?  If so, what are you stuck on?

Comment: More like a language problem. Does $f(x) = 1$ satisfies the condition?

Comment: Your question is: Does there exist a continuous function that takes rational values at irrational points, and irrational values at rational points, right?

Comment: @Eric, If i choose $f(x)=\sqrt {2},$ then according to question this value will be attained at only rational points  and thus will not be a function.However If i  choose $f(x)=1,$  it can be attained at rational as well as irrational point of domain........there is restriction only on attaining irrational values... so what will be next step

Comment: @астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг, No its different from your question, here restriction is only on attaining irrational values not on rational

Comment: @John Ma, It seems that there will be infinite constant continuous map  attaining rational values only i.e $f(x)=c, c\in Q.$ Am I right?

Comment: @Eric Wofsey,  Please look at my claim I have posted above

Comment: Maybe the wording of the question is a little odd. Do you mean that if $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$  implies $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ or do you mean $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$  if and only if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$. In the second case there is no such function in the first case you are right, the constant functions mapping to a rational number are the ones you are looking for. Your reasoning that there can be no nonconstant ones is also fine (you implicitely use the intermediate value theorem but I think you know this).

Comment: @Maik Pickl, I wrote the question as it  is given in the book of Prof. S.Kumeresan, initially it seems that this question is same as suggested  by @ астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг, but it is not so........In case of the question '' Does there exist a continuous function that takes rational values at irrational points, and irrational values at rational points''  ans will be that there exist no such function, but here the question is different as i said above.

Comment: @ You are right that  ''Maybe the wording of the question is a little odd'' Thanks all for your help